# Meteor: collection empty after insert

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and got stucked and can't understand what am I doing wrong. Enlighten me please.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<body>

  <h1>Do</h1>
  {{#if activeTask}}
    {{> currentTask}}
  {{else}}
    {{> newTask }}
  {{/if}}

  <div>

  </div>

</body>


<template name="newTask">
  <form>
    <label>What<input type="text" name="what" placeholder="gimme an action"/></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
  </form>

  <!--
  {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="msg" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="action"}}
  -->

</template>

<template name="currentTask">
  <form>
    <label>What<input type="text" name="what" placeholder="gimme an action"/>{{activeTask.what}}</label>
    <div>4h 15m</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Stop"/>
  </form>
</template>
```

And here is the JavaScript file:

```
tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({

    activeTask: function() {
      var task = tasks.findOne(
        {
          endAt: null
        },
        {
          sort: {
            startAt: -1
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(task);
      return task;
    }

  });

  Template.newTask.events({
    'submit' : function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var now = Date.now();
      var what = event.target.what.value;
      tasks.insert({ what: what, startAt: now, endAt: null });
    }
  });

}
```

It successfully adds a new document into the database and logs this in the helper activeTask. One step later it logs no task at all. It has gone. But why?

Comment: What is one step later? I've tried out your example and it seems to work fine. First it shows the template `newTask` - after you add one it only shows `activeTask`. In case you want to see `newTask` again you need to change your template logic.

Comment: That's strange. In my environment it shows always newTask and gives me an undefined in the console as the last output. The first output is the new created document, the second undefined. Why does he call activeTask twice after submitting the form?

Comment: What OS are you using. Are there any other JS files in your project folder? Please also post your `<project>/.meteor/packages` file. Might be just an access problem (insecure/autopublish)

Comment: Ah, I created it from an example localmarket. The best thing I can do is to delete the complete project and start again.

Comment: I'm assuming your code is correct and you're just missing the publication/subscription (see answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the package `autopublish` (https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/autopublish) installed, you need to create a publication (client-side) and subscription (server-side):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('tasks', function () {
    return tasks.find();
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
}
```

I've also explained [working with collections](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/7cce3ca0-2e7b-4603-90c5-570b646f0dd7/entry/meteor_part_3_collections?lang=en) in a recent blog article.